# Need SQL expression for REPLACE

Tags: sql, replace, import, prestashop, execute

During a CSV file import from external URL i need to execute REPLACE
(I can't edit the CSV file manually/locally cause it's located on the suppliers FTP and will be used in the future for add/dele/update etc of the products in the file on a automated recurring scheduled task)

I got this expression for replacing value of a column in the CSV file:

```
REPLACE([CSV_COL(6)],"TEXSON","EXTERNAL")
```

It's working for column 6 in the CSV file cause all row values of that column is the same(TEXSON)

What i need help with:

In column 5 in the CSV file i have various values and there no connection between these values.
How can i run an expression that replaces all values in column 5 in the CSV with "EXTERNAL"?

See image of how it looks in the CSV file: [image]

Maybe some "wildcard" to just replace everything in that column, no matter what value it is...

*Additional information: Im working with the PrestaShop Store Manager to import products to the shop from our supplier...*

Thanks!

Comment: Can you tried simply adding the text you want to use for all rows as an expression?

Comment: Thats what i want, but i don't know what to use instead of "TEXSON" cause the values in column 5 is all different from each other...

Comment: No idea about the import tool you're using but will it accept "just the text" you want? If not how about any expression that always evaluates true eg `case when 1=1 then "my text" end`?